# frame->False not working

Tags: graphics

[image]

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> False, FrameTicks -> None,  FrameStyle -> Directive[Red, Dotted]]
```

I also tried FrameTicks none, and it doesn't seem to be working either, but that is exactly how it works on the examples page, what could this be caused by?

At first I thought, it was my Installation that was somehow not working but, for example

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}}]
```

Works while

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> {{False, False}, {False, False}}]
```

Will not work..

Comment: That plot has `Axes` and `Ticks`, but it does not have a `Frame` and `FrameTicks`. Use the  `Axes` and `Ticks` options (see also `Graphics` documentation, as well as the example on the `Plot` documentation page).

Comment: Thanks, this solved my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a Plot, and you put a nonempty frame value, this will override the Axes parameter, which is why the example didn't work. 
This can be done with

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 5}, Axes -> False, Ticks -> None]
```

Instead.
[image: the now right plot]